# host public node js website on amazon AWS LightSail without Bitnami

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I have an amazon AWS LightSail instance and have installed Node js downloaded from nodejs.org. Now the setup is complete and I am able to launch my nodejs webpage inside LightSail instance using "http://localhost but when I try to do it using the lightsail public IP from any other laptop, it not getting accessible (getting web error as "This site can’t be reached").

I have set the node js to listen to port 80 which is open by default.

A lot of materials shows that bitnami as a way to do it but can't I use normal node js installation to make the website public. Appreciate any guidance on this

Answer (score 4):

Bitnami Engineer here,

You can configure your Nodejs app to use the port 3000 and then configure Apache to ProxyPass the requests to that port. This way you will be able to access your app using http and https. Does that sound good? You will need to run these commands:

- Create the folders

```
sudo mkdir -p /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp
sudo mkdir /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf
sudo mkdir /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/htdocs
```

- Create a /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-prefix.conf file with this content

```
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-app.conf"
```

- Add this content to the /opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-app.conf file

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

- Add this line to the /opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf file

```
Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/myapp/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
```

- Restart Apache

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

You have more information in our documentation

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/nodejs/administration/create-custom-application-nodejs/

Comment: Thanks, I am on windows server box, can you pls provide instructions for windows server setup for this case?

Comment: It's simple. You will need to change /opt/bitnami with your installation path and use the graphical interface (not the command line) to create the different folders and files and restart the Apache service using [the Bitnami manager](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/faq/windows-faq/administration/control-services-windows/)

Comment: maybe it would be better if your preinstalled version was not 12 in Feb 2024