# Bitnami proxy to node doesn't work after ssl configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache, bitnami, amazon-lightsail

I create an instance on AWS Lightsail with bitnami's node image.

I installed my app and started it, configured everything according to the guides I found, like this one: [host public node js website on amazon AWS LightSail without Bitnami](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60180680/host-public-node-js-website-on-amazon-aws-lightsail-without-bitnami)

For some reason I didn't have `bitnami-apps-prefix.conf` so I created it and then included it in `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf`.
Restarted Apache, and it worked.

Afterward I installed ssl certificate with the provided bncert-tool. after the certificate as added my domain has ssl but I can no longer access my app, I get the default page, the same as I got right after the instance went up:

[image: default page]

I checked and it seems that `bitnami.conf` still includes my addtion of `bitnami-apps-prefix.conf`
I tried to add proxy as the first thing in the virtual host but it doesn't help.

Here is my `/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami.conf` file:

```
# Default Virtual Host configuration.

# Let Apache know we're behind a SSL reverse proxy
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto https HTTPS=on

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs"
  # BEGIN: Configuration for letsencrypt
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apps/letsencrypt/conf/httpd-prefix.conf"
  # END: Configuration for letsencrypt
  # BEGIN: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy without Location
  <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
    ProxyPass /.well-known !
  </IfModule>
  # END: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy without Location
  # BEGIN: Enable HTTP to HTTPS redirection
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+.[0-9]+(:[0-9]+)?$
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known
  RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
  # END: Enable HTTP to HTTPS redirection
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/apache/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # Error Documents
  ErrorDocument 503 /503.html
  #Bitnami applications installed with a prefix URL (default)
  Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"
  # BEGIN: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy within Location
  <Location /.well-known>
    <IfModule mod_proxy.c>
      ProxyPass !
    </IfModule>
  </Location>
  # END: Support domain renewal when using mod_proxy within Location
</VirtualHost>

Include "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/bitnami-ssl.conf"
```

What am I missing here? why requests are not redirected to my app?

Answer (score 0):

I had to add `Include "/opt/bitnami/apache2/conf/bitnami/bitnami-apps-prefix.conf"`
to `/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/bitnami-ssl.conf`.

not sure why it was missing in the first place, from the documentation I understand it's supposed to be there out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here,

It seems you didn't follow the Bitnami documentation. If you take a look at it, there are different steps to configure the VirtualHost in the instance.

https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/infrastructure/nodejs/administration/create-custom-application-nodejs/#step-3-serve-your-application-through-the-apache-web-server

You can either copy the file we generate in the instance

```
sudo cp /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/sample-http-vhost.conf.disabled /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/sample-http-vhost.conf
sudo cp /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/sample-https-vhost.conf.disabled /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/sample-https-vhost.conf
```

or generate those files with the following content

- /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/myapp-http-vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  ServerAlias *
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/projects/myapp/public"
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/projects/myapp/public">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

- /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/vhosts/myapp-https-vhost.conf

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
  ServerAlias *
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.crt"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/bitnami/apache/conf/bitnami/certs/server.key"
  DocumentRoot "/opt/bitnami/projects/myapp"
  <Directory "/opt/bitnami/projects/myapp">
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:3000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:3000/
</VirtualHost>
```

You will need to restart Apache later

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

Comment: I used the sample vhost files and it was working until I used the `bncert-tool` which then generated its own vhost files and now the server is returning 503 errors. I think there is some nuance (which I am not yet sure what the problem is) that could be elaborated in the docs that could help the quality of life here.